# Distribution of sum of a circular uniform and a discrete uniform random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I hope you can help me resolve the following problem:

Let X and Y be circular continuous and discrete uniform random variables, respectively, such that -π≤X≤π and -2^(-q)π ≤ Y ≤ 2^(-q)π with q being a nonnegative integer. What is the distribution of Z = X+Y ?

Any advice would be useful.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: It depends on whether they are independent.  If so, the answer is intuitively obvious (consider them as random rotations)